# ViewController loaded in AppDelegate BUT shifted down

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller, appdelegate

Inside AppDelegate.m file I have:

```
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    self.MainVC  = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.HamMenuVC = [[HamMenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HamMenuViewController" bundle:nil];

    self.RevealVC = [[SWRevealViewController alloc]initWithRearViewController:self.HamMenuVC frontViewController:self.MainVC];

    self.navC = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.RevealVC];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navC;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Which is supposed to load my Main VC and then the hamburger menu VC (or slider? in iOS talk), and when I start the app I get the loaded VCs BUT the entire view seems to be shifted down roughly 30 pixels and there's this white space above.

As you can see below, this is the top of my screen and the black is where the MainVC starts:
[the top of the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fy1lA.png)

I've checked the 'self.view.frame.origin.y' inside the MainVC and it says 0.0 AND I've checked the '[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height' and it's giving me the correct height for the device I'm running it on AND I checked the '[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].origin.y' and it says 0.0.

Does anyone have a clue why all the data is saying it's in the right place but the fact is it's in the wrong place on my physical device AND on any simulator I choose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that's the UINavigationBar on top of the screen. In your code, you're setting your `rootViewController` with a UINavigationController.

```
self.navC = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.RevealVC];
self.window.rootViewController = self.navC;
```

If you need to hide the navigation bar, call this method in your RevealVC's `viewDidLoad` method:

`[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];`

Also, quick tip, try to name your properties starting with lowercase letters.

Comment: thank you that worked! As for the properties, you're right, I need to be more consistent with that cause ive been doing both haha

Comment: Awesome! Good luck :)